# Oreo sticky background service

Tags: android

I have in my app two services 
1. sticky foreground service 
2. sticky background service

Android O OS will restart background service in case you have running foreground service.
the question is when the system close my services is it granted that the foreground service will be restarted by the system before the background service otherwise the background service will never restart.

Comment: Why not combine these into a single service?